# Issue dragging element contained in a draggable element

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

Ey, im having an issue when i drag a draggable div that is contained into another dragabble div.

[Draggable divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbnRh.png)

I have 2 event handlers attached on both divs, but when i drag the div #2 contained in the div #1, it also runs the function for the "ondragstart" of #1, and i only want to run the function of the "ondragstart" of #2.

The functions have different names, obviously. onDragStart1 and onDragStart2.

¿Can someone help me ? thanks :3

Comment: Please post any relevant [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use stopPropagation method in your onDragStart2 function

> The event.stopPropagation() method stops the bubbling of an event to
>   parent elements, preventing any parent event handlers from being
>   executed.